# How to copy file from Application.streamingAssetsPath (Unity Android)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I need to get file path that reside under Application.streamingAssetsPath, but I understood that I can't just get a path to file that located under streaminAssets dir, because this file will be compressed in the apk. So, in order to get the path I need to copy a file from Application.streamingAssetsPath to Application.persistentDataPath and that way I can get path to file.

in order to copy I use this method

```
    IEnumerator CopyFile(string from, string to)
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(from);

        while (!www.isDone)
        {
            //Must yield below/wait for a frame
            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log("Done downloading");

        byte[] yourBytes = www.bytes;
        Debug.Log($"Unity HERE lenght:: {www.bytes.Length}");    <----- here I get 0kb.

        //Now Save it
        File.WriteAllBytes(to, yourBytes);
    }
```

Length of byte array is 0.

problem is - path that I am trying to copy from is : `/jar:file:/data/app/com.co.unityandroidplayer-7msilEGHVZkbwTrDAvgfig==/base.apk!/assets/3.co`, as written in documentation

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html?_ga=2.262004941.1502410520.1604388002-954575440.1598172327

`It is not possible to access the StreamingAssets folder on WebGL and Android platforms`

Ok, so I started to find out how to do it. I found such post

https://forum.unity.com/threads/copying-everyhting-under-streamingassets-to-persistentdatapath-on-android.431269/#post-3276021

It is not completely the same, but here a guy also tried to copy from `Application.streamingAssetsPath`, but I don't understand how it could work? Because there at the end he use this line

```
WWW www = new WWW(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Data.tgz");
```

But again according to documentation(link above) it is not possible to access on android.

So, how to do it? it is weird that I have a file and I know where it reside, but I don't have any options to get path to it. Even copy doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

path to StreamingAssets in Android - "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets"